# WebAPI help pages DTD or XSD schema file generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Is it possible to create DTD or XSD files for a WebAPI project from [WebAPI Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages).  I'm using WebAPI Help Pages to document the request and response models, but I was after producing more formal definition documents.